# "CRS selector" dialog after running a script

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I add an empty vector layer using the following script.

```
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('LineString', 'MyLayer' , 'memory')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

After I run the script, "Coordinate Reference System selector" dialog appear.  How can I get rid of this dialog?  Or, is there a script that will close the dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the CRS when you create your memory layer:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=EPSG:2964', 'MyLayer' , 'memory')
```

Answer (score 1):

Under `Settings -> Options -> CRS` you can specify what CRS a new layer should be given, if it can not be read from file.

Another choice would be to add the CRS to your layer with your script.