# How to write CRS info from QGSVectorLayer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2.14

I'm writing a plugin which will create a new virtual layer containing points. I know the CRS of the new layer, as it is the same as the layer I am using for input. I would like to specify the CRS in code but the CRS selector dialog pops up when I create the layer. I would like to suppress that dialog so that something like this will work.

```
def createVirtualLayer(self):
    self.vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point","block_labels", "memory")
    self.vl.setCrs(self.layer.crs())
```

Comment: Try `self.vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:4386", "block_labels", "memory")` as described in these posts: [How to avoid the CRS Dialog when creating a vector layer memory?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68167/how-to-avoid-the-crs-dialog-when-creating-a-vector-layer-memory) and [“CRS selector” dialog after running a script](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101933/crs-selector-dialog-after-running-a-script) :)

Comment: Thanks, I went looking for that info on the QGIS api page. It's there, but very difficult to find. I expected it to be part of the description of the constructor, or at least linked to from there.

Comment: Yeh, I sometimes find difficulty searching for info from the API pages. I tend to find most answers to my questions here on GIS:SE =)